# Roundcubebox ngnix internal error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04, roundcube

I have problem setting up roundcubebox with nginx, im getting this error:
[image: Error]

Im running php8.1 and php-fpm process is running.
Also I checked nginx and roundcubebox logs, nothing seems unusual.
My nginx config: https://pastebin.com/WBFhucTm

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It by downgrading php version from 8.1 to 7.2